# Edureka - Handle exceptions in Selenium Web Driver - no print out

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, exception, selenium-chromedriver

I am a total noob at Automation Testing and i am trying to learn through Youtube how to do it.

https://youtu.be/FRn5J31eAMw?t=12405

On this course from Edureka there is an example where they are trying to handle an exception, where after they run the script the system shows them a message in the console which i cannot get.

```
package co.edureka.selenium.demo;


import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HandlingExceptions {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.name("fake")).click();    
            
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            
            System.out.println("element is not found");
            System.out.println("Hello");
            
            //throw(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

this is the script in Java they are running and at the end in the console they are getting this as a result
[Edureka Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQjxQ.png)

But i am getting something totally different even though my code is exactly the same.

[My Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wou1T.png)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add `System.out.println(e);` in exception block

Answer (score 1):

your are using "import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
" at top of file so please remove and use below one

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException